# How to find longest words from a text file with any characters?

Tags: java, unicode

My task is to simply retrieve the longest word from a text document.
How do I adjust this to work on any language, such as Russian or Arabic.
Words containing the digits 0-9 are ignored  and any punctuation in a word is stripped before storage

ex. 53-Ð»ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð¸Ð¹ Ð›ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð½?

ex, Ø§Ù„Ø¹ÙŽØ§Ù…ÙŽÙ‘Ø©ÙŽ Ø¹ÙŽÙ„ÙŽÙ‰ Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙŽÙ

my code:

```
public Collection<String> getLongestWords() {

    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));


    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if (current.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = current;

        }
        return longestWord;

    }

}
```

Note: I have never implemented unicode before :/

Comment: You don't need to implement unicode.  You just need to read the file with the same character encoding as it was written.  Most likely the default is ok.  Your code looks file to me, what problem are you having?

Comment: Well my homework is asking me to research Unicode and implement it, but I'm wondering where I would use it in this example.

Comment: unicode is a standard encoding. Are you sure he didn't ask you to use unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go fully working I believe: (finds and returns the longest word in the text file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class hello {
     public static void main(String [ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new hello().getLongestWords();
 }

public String getLongestWords() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));


    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if (current.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = current;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(longestWord);
            return longestWord;
        }

}
```

strip punctuation:

```
    longestWord.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");
```

before you return !

If you want not to take into account words with numbers:

```
if ((current.length() > longestWord.length()) && (!current.matches(".*\\d.*"))) {
```

Everything together:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class hello {
     public static void main(String [ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new hello().getLongestWords();
 }

public String getLongestWords() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));


    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if ((current.length() > longestWord.length()) && (!current.matches(".*\\d.*"))) {
            longestWord = current;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(longestWord);
    longestWord.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");
            return longestWord;
        }

}
```

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick box on the left